# Cannot hide app from recent list when overview button clicks

Tags: java, android

I want to hide my **A** activity from recent list, and i used **excludeFromRecents="true"**, it works fine when i select home button and then select overview button, but when **A** activity is  showing and i press overview button, activity exists in recent list, how can i hide A activity in that situation?

here is my activity tag in manifest :

```
            android:name=".A"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, overwriting Activity **A** onStop and onPause with finish() can maybe solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @L2_Paver but doesn't work.